# How to verify all rows in a HTML table that uses pagination during Cypress test?

Tags: cypress

In my Cypress test, I'm comparing the data on a HTML table (which is paginated) against expected values (which are stored in an array).

Also, the number of records in the table is can vary.

The current amount of rows appearing on the table (the first page) is 5 records, and users can navigate to the other records using the Next/Previous/First/Last buttons as usual.

Here is my latest Cypress code:

```
cy.task('queryDb', `${myQuery}`).then(result => {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {   
        dashboard.name(i).should('have.text', ` ${result[i].name} `)  
    }    
})
```

The above `for` loop works for the 5 companies that appear on the UI, but it doesn't loop through the records that aren't visible on the screen.

Can someone please tell me how I can validate the remaining companies in the table?

Do I only do this for the first 5 records, click the 'Next' button, & then do the same for the next 5 records?

Answer (score 1):

There are two very different things, and you may want to separate them into two tests:

1. You want to test the method that populates your HTML table and make sure you retrieve the expected results
2. You want to ensure that your HTML table is working as expected with the proper pagination

For (1) it would be easier to test your HTML table query URL and see if you can query all without the pagination. In this way, you will be able to ensure that the retrieved data are correct.

For (2) you know the data are correct. You want to make sure they are displayed as expected.. It may be helpful to try and validate the next and previous buttons.

In this way, you will know if the problem comes from the logic inside your UI component or if it comes from your backend.